# Working with threads in c/c++, across many different platforms

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

In my understanding, if you use C, then you are bound to use POSIX Threads.

These are OS dependent, and if you use Linux, you have to use `<pthread.h>`, while if you use Windows, you have to go with `<windows.h>`.

These things are transferable to C++ as well.

However, if you use C++ and specifically a version after C++11, then you can skip the POSIX threads method, and use `#include <thread>` and you are off to go.

Is this a correct understanding? Is there something i miss?

Comment: That about sums it up. There are (were) pthread API libraries for windows too (that just wrap, where possible, native Windows threading), but with the advent of  C++11 and `<thread>` sanity suggests you use that instead. (and my goodness, was there ever much rejoicing when that came down).

Comment: MinGW (at least the one from MSYS2) still bases their `<thread>` support on a Windows port of pthread, I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since C11, there is a support of threads *directly in the standard C language* (using `threads.h`). Note that mainstream compilers (Clang, GCC, ICC, MSVC) support *OpenMP* which can be used to parallelize computing codes using multiple threads (typically numerical codes). OpenMP is available in both C and C++ (as well as FORTRAN). Note also that PThreads is supported on Windows as a wrapping library. In pre-C++11, note that there is many portable threading libraries. One famous library is the Intel Threading Building Blocks (aka TBB).

Related question: [Multi-Threading support in c11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876043/multi-threading-support-in-c11)

Comment: In other words, to the OP's "*Is this a correct understanding?*" **No.** "*Is there something i miss?*", **Yes, lots.**